# How to Troubleshoot Java JRE Windows 8.1 Installation (the installer does nothing, reports no errors)

Tags: java, windows, installation, windows-8.1

I am trying to install the latest Java JRE for Windows 8.1:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

And none of the installers work. Online/Offline/x86/x64

I double-click the installer, get the UAC popup, approve, and then it thinks for a second and then just does nothing.  How can I troubleshoot this more?

Things I've Tried:

1. Disabling UAC
2. Disabling all anti-virus
3. Disabling Windows Firewall / Defender
4. Downloading older version of Java (still does nothing when run)
5. Running as Administrator
6. Launching from admin-command-line
7. Changing compatibility mode (all of vista -> windows 7)
8. Running in Safe Mode (same behavior)
9. Uninstalling all older Java installations (big mistake)
10. Monitoring Process List - the java installer pops up for a second and 
    disappears
11. Installing through the JDK - JDK installer also does nothing when launched
12. Event Viewer shows no errors

I can't find any logs or errors that might help narrow down what the issue could be.

Any help would be very much appreciated. If there are any additional tools I could check out to help with troubleshooting, or any logs people know of, I could use any help I could get.

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you get when running the executable from the command line (as admin)? any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it does nothing*"?

Comment: What folders are within `C:\Program Files\Java`?

Comment: There's nothing in C:\Program Files\Java (I uninstalled the previous version) and when I mean "it does nothing"  I mean I double-click the installation .exe and it spins the cursor for a second ("thinking") and then - nothing!     When I try launching the .exe from command line it has the same behavior.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fiddling around, I think I finally have something working. It seems that there's some weirdness for any system that has ever upgraded their version of Windows (I went from 8 to 8.1) with some sort of MSI ID sort of thing.  So, here's how I finally ended up:

HOW I FIXED:

1) The issue started after the Java 8 "51" installer.  So the 51 still works, get it here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

You want:  jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe (or i586)

Install older version

2) download latest Java .zip archive (like jre-8u91-windows-i586.tar.gz )  and unzip it in any location, preferably "c:\Program Files\Java"

3) Go to "C:\Program Files\Java"  and rename jre1.8.0_51 to something else ("jre1.8.0_51_bak" maybe)

4) Copy the contents of the extracted .tar.gz contents into a new folder named "c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_51" (or rename the directory)

So basically using the install directory for 51, but adding the latest Java files into the folder that the installation is pointing at.

Quick fix, for now, just to help anybody in a pinch.  I'll update as I continue to sort it out and if there's any new information.

Good luck!